# RegEx to match and select specific URLs

Tags: regex, url, regex-lookarounds, regex-group, regex-greedy

I’m on a website with these URLs;

```
https://flyheight.com/videos/ybb347
https://flyheight.com/videos/yb24os
https://flyheight.com/public/images/videos/793f77362f321e62c32659c3ab00952d.png
https://flyheight.com/videos/5o6t98/#disqus_thread
```

I need a RegEx that will only select these URLs instead

```
https://flyheight.com/videos/yb24os
https://flyheight.com/videos/ybb347
```

This is what I got so far `^(?!images$).*(flyheight.com/videos/).*`

Comment: What regex engine are you using?

Comment: Why the third one is not selected?

Comment: I have used regex101 and my point is I need a regex that will select all the all the links but the third one

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not too sure if this is what you were looking for, but you could use the following:

```
^(?!images$).*(flyheight.com/videos/)([^/]+)$
```

The idea is that it would match the first part that you had, then match one or more characters that is not a slash `([^/]+)` .

If you had strings that may or may not contain the / on the end (for example, you had https://flyheight.com/videos/yb24os or https://flyheight.com/videos/yb24os/), you can try the following:

```
^(?!images$).*(flyheight.com/videos/)([^/]+)/?$
```

[here are my results on regexr.](https://regexr.com/4dp73)

[image: included testing sample if asked]

Comment: Ok I just did it

Answer (score 2):

PCRE: `^https?:\/\/flyheight\.com\/videos\/[a-z0-9]{6}$`

https://regex101.com/r/vM31MK/1

May be this will also work for your language:
`^https?://flyheight\.com/videos/[a-z0-9]{6}$`

Comment: this is the right answer. The other answer will start to break unexpectedly if you pass in something slightly wrong

Answer (score 0):

[This simple expression](https://regex101.com/r/xTSkoA/1) might do that since all your desired output starts with an `y`:

```
\/(y.*)
```

However, if you wish to add additional boundaries to it, you can do so. For instance, [this](https://regex101.com/r/R2KOrY/1) would strengthen the left boundary:

```
flyheight.com\/videos\/(y.*)
```

Or you could add a list of char, similar to [this](https://regex101.com/r/RJp1qe/1):

```
flyheight.com\/videos\/([a-z0-9]+)
```

You can also add a quantifier to the desired output, similar to [this expression](https://regex101.com/r/0lDAjp/1):

```
flyheight.com\/videos\/([a-z0-9]{6})
```

and you can simply increase and add any boundary that you wish and capture your desired URLs, and fail others.

[image]

You might want to use [this tool](https://regex101.com/r/zYCnav/1/) and change/edit/modify your expression based on your desired engine, as you wish:

```
^(.*)(flyheight.com\/videos\/)([a-z0-9]{6})$
```

This graph shows how it works and you can test more expressions [here](https://jex.im/regulex/#!flags=&re=%5E(a%7Cb)*%3F%24):

[image]